# SELECT INTO OUTFILE giving OS errno 13

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

We recently migrated from `MySQL5.6.51` to `MySQL8.0.28` (`Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`) and we have started noticing some differences.  One of the problems has been recreated using a sample database, with a table called `people`.

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_Sandbox |
+-------------------+
| people            |
+-------------------+
```

We can SELECT INTO OUTFILE to `/tmp` directory without any issues.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM people INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/people.txt';
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

However, we are getting are getting an error with another directory (let us call it `/mysql_tmp`), even though it has 777 permissions and user and group are `mysql`

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM people INTO OUTFILE '/mysql_tmp/people.txt';
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/mysql_tmp/people.txt' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
```

Here is the truncated output of `ls -l`:

```
$ ls -l /
...
drwxrwxrwx   2 mysql       mysql           4096 Apr  5 13:52 mysql_tmp
...
drwxrwxrwt  26 root        root            4096 Apr  5 14:17 tmp
...
```

Comment: Does the file already exist in that dir? Also what the permissions are inside dir, if you issued chown/chmod whiteout -R option maybe permissions are different inside

Comment: Let's see `ls  -ld  /`

Comment: I have seen this kind of error happen on Ubuntu as a result of AppArmor denying access to the mysqld service. You can read about configuring AppArmor to allow a non-standard directory: https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-configure-apparmor-mysql-based-systems-mysqlmariadb-replication-galera